# Testing HazelcastClient using TestHazelcastInstance

Tags: java, spring-boot, integration-testing, hazelcast, spring-boot-test

There's a spring-boot based hazelcast microservice that connects to the hazelcast cluster via a `HazelcastClient`.

What would be the process of writing an integration test, given the cluster is mocked using a `TestHazelcastInstance`?

Tried creating a `@TestConfiguration` config class that provides a `TestHazelcastInstance`, but in that case another config class, `HazelcastConfig` (providing the client), didn't seem to be executing, resulting in the client instance not being instantiated.

Any insight?

**App.java**:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {

    public static void main( final String[] args ) {
        SpringApplication.run( App.class, args );
    }
}
```

**HazelcastConfig.java** (providing the client):

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties( prefix = "hazelcast" )
@Getter
@Setter
public class HazelcastConfig {

    private ClientConfig config;

    @Bean
    public HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance() {
        return HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient( config );
    }
}
```

**AppTest.java**, the test in question:

```
@RunWith( SpringRunner.class )
@SpringBootTest( classes = { TestConfig.class } )
@ActiveProfiles( "test" )
public class AppTest {

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }
}
```

**TestConfig.java**, providing the `TestHazelcastInstance`

```
@TestConfiguration
@Profile( "test" )
@ConfigurationProperties( prefix = "hazelcast.server" )
public class TestConfig {

    private Config config;

    @Bean( "hazelcastInstance_TEST" )
    public HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance() {
        return new TestHazelcastInstanceFactory( 1 ).newHazelcastInstance( config );
    }
}
```

Comment: How is the **config** object initialised? what error log do you see during instantiation of the client?

Comment: @laur kindly check the answer and mark it as answered. let me know if you have other questions.

Answer (score 3):

Given it is an integration test you may want to test using an embeded instance of Hazelcast: 
`HazelcastInstance testInstance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);`

Comment: Upvoted. This is how the Hazelcast team themselves unit test the product: https://github.com/hazelcast-guides/hazelcast-embedded-springboot/blob/master/src/test/java/guides/hazelcast/springboot/CommandControllerIT.java#L72

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of unit testing hazelcast code using `TestHazelcastFactory`

```
public class NativeTestingHazelcast {

    private TestHazelcastFactory hazelcastFactory = new TestHazelcastFactory();

  private HazelcastInstance member;
  private HazelcastInstance client;

 @Before
 public void setUp() throws Exception {
     member = hazelcastFactory.newHazelcastInstance();
     client = hazelcastFactory.newHazelcastClient();
 }

 @Test
 public void simpleTest() throws Exception {
     final IMap<Integer, String> testMapFromMember = member.getMap("testMap");
     testMapFromMember.set(1, "test1");

    final IMap<Integer, String> testMap = client.getMap("testMap");
    final String value = testMap.get(1);
    assertEquals("member puts, client gets", value, "test1");
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    hazelcastFactory.shutdownAll();
  }
}
```

Let me know if you have any other questions.

Cheers

Vik